# Why suddenly, localhost runs slowly?

Tags: reactjs

All of the sudden, when I use npm start on any of my projects, it just keeps loading them.
Any idea why did it happen? Didn't happen to me before, just now.
I'm working only with React.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with PHP. I solved it by changing "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" in database connection parameters like someone suggested here: https://serverfault.com/a/444338/62739 . I think it may work for you too, give it a try.

Comment: Although I don't think its the same problem, because mine just keeps loading - and it suddenly happens with all of my react apps, not just a single one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I suggested using the raw IP address for localhost is because Windows does not directly support the type of connection that MySQL/MariaDB tries to use when localhost is specified. This will result in delays of up to several seconds on every page load.

Comment: This is more then just few seconds, it takes a few minutes.